# How to get key object from Dictionary by key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

In my application, I have a dictionary with key/value objects

```
Dictionary<TObject,VObject> list
```

To check if I have the object, I'm using a special instance of `TObject` and checking if it exists in the list.

After i get `TRUE`, I need to get the original Key object (`TObject`)

```
VObject result = list[TObject]; // will return me the VObject
```

The original `TObject` (the key), has more values that have been initialized on the object creation and I need to do a test on them.

How can i do this?

Comment: You can grab a instance of your keys using,  list.Keys.FirstOrDefault( * comparision to TObject*); linq query, does this help you?

Comment: Thanks, its working.

Comment: I see that you're using an object as the Dictionary's key. In case you're building a performance-sensitive app, beware that indexing a dictionary by anything other than the [built-in types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) can be an order of magnitude slower than just using a string or a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary object contains `Keys` property, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

You can run queries against this property to select the key you are looking for.

Usage with LINQ:

```
var foundKey = dictionaryObject.Keys.FirstOrDefault( * Linq Expression* );
```

Comment: linq expression : (x => x.Equals(TObject))

Comment: Just ensure you use the right comparer for Equals check. Dictionaries can have custom comparers.